# Show content without a post

Tags: plugin-development, permalinks

I am writing a plugin, and want to show an about page, but without a post/page record.
So if, the url https://example.com/about is entered, my 'hardcoded' content is shown.

A bit like the login page, there is no login post, but the login screen displays.

Which hooks would I need to use to catch the url, and then output my content without getting a 404?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try 'request' hook:

```
add_filter('request', function( $vars ) {

    $request = urldecode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    if ( stristr($request, '/YOUR_SLUG') != false ) {
        ...
    }
}
```